# All we seem to do is argue or is arguing

Tags: grammar, present-continuous

Another strange sentence I found in a grammar book: "All we seem to do is argue."
I thought it should be arguing.  I could not find the noun argue in any dictionary.  Could you explain this?

Comment: Why are you looking for a noun entry for *argue*?

Comment: @Lawrence - My guess is that the OP took a structure like: _All we seem to eat is food,_ and reckoned a noun should come after _is_, not realizing that, unlike _eat_, _do_ would be followed by a verb rather than a noun. Now I have [Don Henley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_She_Wants_to_Do_Is_Dance) running through my head. Anyway, this seems like it would be much more fitting on [ell.se].

Comment: @J.R. That sounds plausible. I'll vote to migrate this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case "argue" is the bare infinitive.  Infinitives can be the complement in a sentence, in a structure like

> All we do is argue.
>   What we do is be kind.

Note the choice of a bare infinitive is dependent on the verb "do".

> All I want is to argue

This is because the structure is formed from "We do argue", which has bare infinitive following "do". But "We want to argue", which has a "to" infinitive after want.

Answer (score 2):

After the word do, we are supposed to talk about an activity and we should use a verb, not a noun. Using "arguing" is not correct here. Your sentence should be like this:

> All we seem to do is argue .

or

> All we seem to do is to argue.

Although adding "to" is optional, using bare infinitive is preferable and sounds more natural.

Comment: However, it's not *always* the case that a verb must follow: *I'm going to do the dishes*, *I have to do the laundry* . . .