# Expressions like "All I am doing lately is" should be fallowed by "listening to music" or "listen to music"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I have read the following links and have a question similar to them:

[All we seem to do is argue or is arguing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176647/all-we-seem-to-do-is-argue-or-is-arguing)

[“All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/all-you-have-to-do-is-read-vs-all-you-have-to-do-is-to-read)

["What I have to do is" + verb inf](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106058/what-i-have-to-do-is-verb-inf)

[What form of verb should expressions like "All I want to do is" be followed by?](https://www.quora.com/What-form-of-verb-should-expressions-like-All-I-want-to-do-is-be-followed-by)

Based on these links, I suppose the sentence:

> 1. "All I do lately is listen to music".

is right, and the sentence:

> 2. All I do lately is listening to music.

is wrong.

But what about these:

> 3. "All I am doing now is listen to music".

> 4. "All I am doing now is listening to music".

Does the present continuous form of the verb ("doing") makes the phrase coming after "is" to be a gerund?

Maybe the original form of this sentence is

> 5. "All I am doing now is **[I am]** listening to music".

Where **[I am]** is omitted so it is reasonable that the present continuous form of the verb ("doing") propagates to the phrase after "is".

What ever the answer is, can I generalize the answer to all the following expressions?

> 6. What I have been doing lately is study/studying.
> 7. The work that I have been doing lately is draw/drawing a painting.
> 8. The dream that I am thinking about is go/going on a trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when the first main verb has an "ing" form, the second should also have an "ing" form<sup>1</sup>:

> 4. All I am doing now is listening to music.
> 5. What I have been doing lately is studying.
> 6. The work that I have been doing lately is drawing a painting.
> 7. The dream that I am thinking about is going on a trip.

Note that one usually neither "draws" a painting nor "thinks" about a dream. Those sentences are certainly possible but a bit unusual.

Furthermore, there can be some ambiguity; for example, if "going" were a present participle (instead of a gerund), then we might wonder whether the dream was going on a trip for business or for pleasure. In this case it should be obvious that that is not the intended meaning, but in other sentences it could cause some confusion.

---

<sup>1</sup>You didn't ask about full infinitives, but they are sometimes possible. For example: "The idea that I'm proposing is to start a new business."